# How to detect dog bark?

Tags: microcontroller, fpga, signal-processing, fft

I need to design a small dog bark detector. It should be as cheap as possible (10$ manufactured unit.) It should be accurate because it can be used anywhere in noisy places.

The aproach I am considering is to use a small FPGA. Take FFT of sampled signal and try to see in FFT window, which bin crosses threshold and if that bin  belongs to frequency of dog bark, declare it as dog bark. The disadvantage of using FPGA is cost. Cost will increase the required budget limits.

Another aproach is to useba microcontroller (may be an Arduino.) The disadvantage is that FFT cannot be performed real time. During the time the microcontroller is calculating the FFT, the input data for that time will be missed.

Is there any other versatile and cheap way for detecting dog barks with almost no false detection?

Comment: Why do you need to design it? Is this a school assignment? Why have you limited yourself to either an 8-bit Arduino or an FPGA, as there might be many suitable MCUs and DSPs running at hundreds of MHz and capable of running FFTs realtime. Also different dogs bark differently, how are you going to detect barks of all different dogs? How much exactly is "almost none" false detection?

Comment: Adeel, The very first step in any project like this is to collect ***lots*** of data. You need to perhaps capture as much data as you possible can afford to capture. Include all of the different circumstances you intend to solve. ***All*** of them. And make sure that you capture more than one in each. I'd recommend at least a dozen, if not hundreds, in each circumstance. Then you can process that data to see what nature shows you about it. Very, very likely if you are handy with data processing tools, you will find a few key elements that can be used.

Comment: Adeel, Once you have identified these key elements, you can come back here and ask for help. At that point, you will have ***expert knowledge*** on the topic. Which is exactly what you need. If you expect us to be experts on dog barks, you probably need to re-think that. We might have opinions. But I doubt any of us is an expert on the topic. That is ***your*** job to become. Not ours. But if you are a dog-bark expert and come here with expert knowledge on the topic, I think some here would be able to help you.

Comment: @Adeelasif:  There are microprocessors and digital signal processors that are fully capable of doing an FFT in real time.  I think you need to examine lots of dog barks and see not only the frequency content but also how the frequency content changes over time.  Consider the difference in the sound of the bark of a Chihuahua compared to the bark of a Saint Bernhard dog.  Just picking a particular bin (or bins) of the FFT is unlikely to be sufficient, let alone highly accurate.

Comment: There's really no reason to think that an FFT is the correct first step for a problem like this, especially if you want it to work reliably with lots of background noise.

Comment: Get a dog. Nobody would notice the existence of another dog better. You must only learn to read it.

Comment: `frequency of dog bark` ... it seems that you do not know much about dogs ... dogs do not all have the same voice

Comment: Bark recognition sounds like a good application for AI. Obtain recordings of a large number of dog barks and use them to train your AI. Also, it is much easier to get funding if you are using AI. Venture capitalists love to write checks for AI companies. Just tell them your business model is to get acquired by alphabet.

Comment: You can collect the data by having a contest. Give away a prize. To enter you must send in a video of your dog barking. Max length 5 seconds. Must contain dog barking. Winner picked randomly from all qualified entries. Give them an apple laptop if they win. 2nd prize is a petsmart gift card. Third prize is a 2022 dog calendar.

Comment: Not all Arduinos are the same. I have a K210 board that is supported by the Arduino tools that will do your FFT and play Tetris at the same time. One of the demo apps is face detection. As others have intimated, the choice of hardware is immaterial at this point - having an algorithm to detect a dog bark is the hurdle you would need to overcome. Then the choice of hardware would be much easier.

Comment: Everybody can hear when a dog barks. So what's the purpose of detecting a dog bark?

Comment: @MituRaj dogs are not always accompanied by people. Maybe there could be some use case where microphones are listening to a dog bark and need to distinguish the dog bark from other noise.

Comment: Search for “tensorflow dog bark”, that should give a a decent starting point.

Answer (score 4):

You wrote your detection idea:

> try to see in FFT window, which bin crosses threshold and if that bin
> belongs to frequency of dog bark, declare it as dog bark.

As you have read in comments some of us do not believe this will work. There is no such thing as dog's barking frequency. So many things are able to produce so many frequencies that nearly any frequency can belong to numerous different objects. The unique feature in dog's bark which is common for dogs but doesn't exist in other usual sounds is something much more complex than a certain frequency. Before you can detect it you must know what it is. Then you have a theoretical possibility to find what math can extract it from a digitized sound stream.

To stay in truth I have no evidence that FFT is useless as a part of that calculation but I'm afraid that you have as little evidence for the usefulness of FFT in bark detection.

Artificial intelligence research in math PhD level has produced algorithms which can extract what common features a set of signal samples contain. These algorithms have made possible to find how human speech can be recognized and translated to text. Just now an university at about 40 km southwards from where I live tries to collect enough speech samples of our tribal language. Computers do not recognize here other spoken languages than English and that's tried to get changed.

You must collect a big library of dog barks and  common disturbing noises. Then you can start extracting what math feature makes the bark samples dog's bark and different than other noises.

I'm afraid that a 4 year period of academic studies of math and applied math are also needed. Because you know the existence of FFT and seem to have at least some self-confidence the job may well be possible to do.

This randomly selected article of an artificial intelligence project may give some picture of the field: https://mikesmales.medium.com/sound-classification-using-deep-learning-8bc2aa1990b7

BTW. Any dog recognize the sound of other dogs without 4 years of math studies. But their studying effort has been common for the whole specie and it has continued  maybe a million years. I'm afraid that dogs as a specie have got substantial head start when compared to any mathematician or computer programmer, so do not get disappointed if your efforts do not bring the same detection accuracy than dogs have.

Comment: Very nicely written. +1 It doesn't advance what's already in comments. But it distills the essential elements and then composes them into a very readable and understandable statement of the situation at hand. It's as close to an answer the OP is likely to get here. Just to add another thought that crossed my mind: The OP should start by searching the literature for *dogs*, *sound categories*, *category formation*,  *evidence-based taxonomies*, *fluctuation*, *sharpness*, and *acoustic signal features*. That might lead to added search parameters, too.

Comment: Get what's in the literature, first. Take what's been done, examine the experimental setups, decide if those setups were appropriate or if changes are needed to better elicit answers to questions at hand, and then design and perform additional experiments. Those experiments themselves may illustrate (call out) prior unknowns that need to be brought under experimental management and then retried. Or new experiments designed. Repeat/rinse/repeat,... An aspect of all research is that you don't know what you don't know. So it may all end with "no result." Then publish in 5th tier mag no one reads.

Comment: I’m really not sure you need 4 years of study to get this done, as you can rely on the many more years of work that have already been done by others and gracefully been published as freeware. This seems like a classic case of so-called AI. You do indeed need a large library of actual dog barks and another of other sounds which are not dog barks, and train an existing engine with those. This could give pretty good results, though of course even humans may not correctly identify a dog bark, so there will be false positives and negatives.